# available Devices google play

Tags: android, google-play

How I can know the error of compatibility of a device? [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAe4d.png)

Exist any log ?

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xx.xx.xx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 19
    versionName "1.2.2"
}
```

Comment: I read "compatible multiples apks" but is so hard, and I use  in my manifest - >"telephony,touchscreen required = false", only I added 9 devices ... but I need add more devices ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this lines :

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony.cdma"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony.gsm"
    android:required="false" />
```